# Laravel cors with video js (m3u8)

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, video.js

I have installed a fresh Laravel application and fresh ReactJs project for the frontend for uploading videos, [protonemedia/laravel-ffmpeg](https://github.com/protonemedia/laravel-ffmpeg) package for HLS support and when uploaded there is no problem but when response the video first response is good but the (.ts files) will be cors policy

and this is the console error

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YATd6.png

and this is the network tab requests

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d96gh.png

I know the response is 200 but the response body is empty and the request color is red

ReactJs Component File

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import videojs from "video.js";
import "video.js/dist/video-js.css";

const Video = () => {
  const videoNode = useRef(null);
  const [player, setPlayer] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    videojs.Hls.xhr.beforeRequest = function (options) {
      options.headers = {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      };
      return options;
    };
    if (videoNode.current) {
      const _player = videojs(videoNode.current, {
        fill: true,
        fluid: true,
        autoplay: true,
        controls: true,
        preload: "metadata",
        isCorsOrigin: true,
        crossOrigin: "use-credentials",
        withCredentials: true,
        sources: [
          {
            src: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/video-get/video.m3u8",
            type: "application/x-mpegURL",
          },
        ],
      });
      setPlayer(_player);
      return () => {
        if (player !== null) {
          player.dispose();
        }
      };
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div data-vjs-player>
      <video ref={videoNode} className="video-js"></video>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Video;
```

Laravel Route For Uploading

```
Route::post('/video-upload', function (Request $request) {
    try {
        $videoName = 'video.mp4';
        Storage::disk('temp_videos')->put($videoName, base64_decode(explode(',', $request->post('video'))[1]));
        $lowFormat  = (new X264('aac'))->setKiloBitrate(500);
        $highFormat = (new X264('aac'))->setKiloBitrate(1000);
        FFMpeg::fromDisk('temp_videos')
            ->open($videoName)
            ->exportForHLS()
            ->addFormat($lowFormat, function (HLSVideoFilters $filters) {
                $filters->resize(1280, 720);
            })
            ->addFormat($highFormat)
            ->toDisk('public')
            ->save('video.m3u8');
    } catch (EncodingException $exception) {
        return response()->json([
            'error' => $exception->getMessage()
        ], 500);
    }
});
```

Laravel Read Route

```
Route::get('/video-get/{playlist}', function ($playlist) {
    return FFMpeg::dynamicHLSPlaylist()
        ->fromDisk('public')
        ->open($playlist)
        ->setPlaylistUrlResolver(function ($playlist) {
            return 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/video-get/' . $playlist;
        })
        ->setMediaUrlResolver(function ($media) {
            return Storage::disk('public')->url($media);
        });
});
```

and in laravel part I accepted all origins in cors.php file

```
return [
    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,
];
```

and I tried everything like using header() function and using allow access origin in frontend and using custom cors middleware and searched for it every everywhere but I did't find the solution.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you check after cleaning the browser history or open to check the browser in incognito mode?
2. Which laravel version are you currently using?

Comment: 1- I already check it but still not working.
2- Laravel version 9

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: In laravel 9 no need to add cors policy as it already added. If you using with docker need to configure cors policy in Nginx or apache what server you are using. For Nginx https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/enable-cors-nginx/ and  for Apache https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/enable-cors-apache-web-server/. I thought the problem you already fixed.